# Flutter - How to set showModalBottomSheet to full height but below status bar?

Tags: flutter

I am able to make bottomSheet to full height by using `showModalBottomSheet(...)` and set the property `isScrollControlled:true`.

However, the bottom sheet is over the status bar, and that is not what I expect.

[image]

Is it possible to make it below the status bar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

as an option you can modify bottom sheet
1. create new file custom_bottom_sheet.dart
2. copy-paste all code from bottom_sheet class into your custom class
3. modify buildPage() method like this

```
  @override
  Widget buildPage(BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation, Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
    final BottomSheetThemeData sheetTheme = theme?.bottomSheetTheme ?? Theme.of(context).bottomSheetTheme;
    Widget bottomSheet = SafeArea(
      child: _ModalBottomSheet<T>(
        route: this,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor ?? sheetTheme?.modalBackgroundColor ?? sheetTheme?.backgroundColor,
        elevation: elevation ?? sheetTheme?.modalElevation ?? sheetTheme?.elevation,
        shape: shape,
        clipBehavior: clipBehavior,
        isScrollControlled: isScrollControlled,
        enableDrag: enableDrag,
      ),
    );
    if (theme != null) bottomSheet = Theme(data: theme, child: bottomSheet);
    return bottomSheet;
  }
```

4. use your class

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'custom_bottom_sheet.dart' as bs;

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(child: Page()),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class Page extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text('show'),
            onPressed: () {
              bs.showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                isScrollControlled: true,
                builder: (context) => Container(color: Colors.red),
              );
            },
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

here is modified bottom_sheet class https://pastebin.com/5U7fsqCw

also I think you need to add property

```
barrierColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0),
```

to prevent status bar dimming

Comment: Thanks it works well. So putting the bottomSheet inside SafeArea makes the magic. :D

Comment: `removeTop: true,` in the code seems to be the real problem.

Comment: why this is not by default use SafeArea :O

Answer (score 17):

Since 20 Jul 2022, you can set `useSafeArea` parameter to `true` to show modal under status bar, [you can find details here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/107140).

```
showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  useSafeArea: true, // <<<<< use this
  // ....
);
```

> Note: Now it available on `master` channel only, and later will be
> available on `stable` channel.

Answer (score 8):

**No need to create a new class.** Simply assign a variable to the padding on the build of your view and use it when opening the dialog.

```dart
class MyHomeScreenState extends State<MyHomeScreen> {
  double? topPadding;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
  //...
  }
```

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        useRootNavigator: true,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                topPadding!,
            color: Colors.green,
          );
});
```

If you look at `SafeArea` source code this is exactly what is happening. Make sure that your build is at a 'root' level on the widget tree since descendant widgets might not have a top padding because they are not underneath the edges.

Comment: Best answer, thanks! Although, Instead of a `Container` with full height, it's simpler to wrap the `Widget` in the builder with a `Padding` and use `EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top)`

Comment: Best way to handle this non sense of showModalBottomSheet. Big thank you to you!!! For anyone who uses an AppBar just do like this: `topPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + AppBar().preferredSize.height ;`

Answer (score 2):

Another easy workaround with rounded borders

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    builder: (context) => Container(
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.965,
         decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                 topLeft: const Radius.circular(16.0),
                 topRight: const Radius.circular(16.0),
              ),
          ),
          child: Center(
              child: Text("Your content goes here"),
    ),
),
```

);

[image]

Comment: This is incorrect. With value `MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.965` you can't guarantee that the `BottomSheet` will look the same way on all devices, especially on devices with notch/built-in cameras where the status bar is usually higher. For such devices your solution might make `BottomSheet` appear behind the status bar.

Comment: @VolodymyrBuberenko, Agreed. 1st answer is the correct one. If you wanna a responsive BottomSheet like mentioned above, you have to create a custom widget.

I just showed a border-rounded BottomSheet without repeating the first answer. what's the remaining part is just pass the BoxDecoration part with the builder to the custom widget.

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution is the most suitable for now: (use `FractionallySizedBox`)

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  enableDrag: true,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  builder: (context) => FractionallySizedBox(
    heightFactor: 0.9,
    child: Container()
  )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

The best and the easiest way is to subtract the total height of device from status bar height. You can get statusBarHeight by MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top and whole device height by MediaQuery.of(context).size.height

Answer (score 1):

You can use the constraints parameter and set the height you want

```
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(35),
          topRight: Radius.circular(35),
        ),
      ),
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 
           MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 50),
      builder: (context) {
         //continue coding..
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Roddy R's answer but a little simpler

```
showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            isScrollControlled: true,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20))),
            builder: (ctx) => Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top),
              child: YourCustomBottomSheet(),
            ),
          ),
```

Thanks Roddy!

Answer (score 0):

As AnasSafi's answer stated, use `useSafeArea: true` to solve this problem. However there are many other tricky issues to solve when creating a bottom sheet. Here is my complete working bottom sheet creator function, which will hopefully help someone.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future Function() openBottomSheet(BuildContext context, Widget child,
    {String? title}) {
  return () => showModalBottomSheet(
        // Don't let bottom sheet extend past the top of the safe area
        useSafeArea: true,
        context: context,
        // Round the top of the bottom sheet
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
        ),
        // Add scrollbar when necessary
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (context) => ScrollableWidget(
          child: Container(
            // Move bottom sheet above on-screen keyboard, if keyboard is open
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // Add back button at top left of bottom sheet (since it's
                // not obvious that sheet can be swiped down to close it)
                const BackButton(),
                Padding(
                  // Pad the main widget (larger padding on the top to leave
                  // space for the back button)
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 35.0, 20.0, 25.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // Make content full-width, so that main widget is
                      // centered even if it doesn't expand
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: const [SizedBox(height: 0)],
                      ),
                      // Add title text to top of bottom sheet, if provided
                      title == null
                          ? Container()
                          : Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  title,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 18),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(height: 8),
                              ],
                            ),
                      // Add the main widget
                      child,
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
}

/// A scrollable widget with a scrollbar that is shown when necessary
class ScrollableWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ScrollableWidget({super.key, required this.child});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<ScrollableWidget> createState() => _ScrollableWidgetState();
}

class _ScrollableWidgetState extends State<ScrollableWidget> {
  final controller = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      thumbVisibility: true,
      thickness: 15,
      radius: const Radius.circular(8),
      controller: controller,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        // Same controller must be used on Scrollbar and SingleChildScrollView
        controller: controller,
        child: widget.child,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```